# Select query with sorting for cassandra with stratio lucene index, version >2.2

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-lucene-index

I am trying to test out stratio lucene index for Cassandra database in various release versions, and I'm having a problem when going past version 2.2:

Suppose I have a table with a column `mymap` which is of type `map<text, text>`, and I have it indexed with sorting options using lucene index:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX myindex
ON mytable (lucene_index)
USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
    'refresh_seconds': '10',
    'schema' : '{            
        fields : {
            mymap: {
              type: "string",
              sorted: true
            }
        }
    }'
};
```

Up until version 2.1 of cassandra - lucene suite I was able to have a working select query which involved lucene index sorting:

```
select * from mytable
where lucene_index = '{
    sort: {
        fields: [{field:"mymap.attr"}]
    }, 
    refresh: true
}';
```

The query would fetch results sorted by the `attr1` map value of the `mymap` column, given that there were rows with that specific map attribute for the column.

When going past version 2.2 all the `element.property` syntax for queries, filters or sorts was changed to `element$property`, however if I make the change in my select query the sorting won't work, and I can even reference inexistent fields within the column.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug involving 2.2.X branch. 
Now it is fixed in [2.2.7.1](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/tree/2.2.7.1).